# Finding the continuous increase in speed while diving toward the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

https://youtu.be/HJO6WuoytGA?t=39s
In this game, the character jumps from the top of the Empire State Building (443.2m), and in a fraction of a second, he breaks Mach 1 just by releasing a great deal of energy, as the sonic boom appears before he completely extends his body.

I know in free fall, objects fall at the same rate, but I'm not sure if free falling formulas apply here. That said, I'm trying to figure out how much more speed he gains (preferably in m/s) as he dives down. Basically, I want to know if he starts at Mach 1, is it possible that he ends at Mach 2 for example, because he's still gaining speed, while figuring out how much speed he is gaining until his motion is at rest.

Hopefully that is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the character switches off his power pack at the top of the building so that only gravity is making him acclerate then you can use the kinematic equation $v^2 = u^2+2as$ to find the speed $v$ at the ground. $u$ is the initial speed, $a=g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, and $s$ is the distance fallen.

$g$ is usually given in units of $m/s^2$ so you will have to convert $u$ to $m/s$.

Comment: It probably doesn't help that he ends up breaking Mach 2 before he hits the ground (game mechanics)